# how to use download attribute in spring with jsp

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I am using download attribute in `jsp`  but I am unable to download the files. Please let me know my issue

```
          <div>
          <p><h3><b>Download EMPLOYEE DOCUMENT LIST :</b></h3></p>
          <c:forEach items="${documentList}" var="doc">
          <h4><u><a href="${doc.path}" download>${doc.docName}</a></u></h4>
          </c:forEach>
          </div>
```

[By default documents are coming from database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a1zQz.png)
      Now, I am going to click on link. It's getting failed no file.

Comment: Please add more code, initialy your JSP is correct you have issue on the method that getting PDF file from DB

Comment: Can you post the error/stacktrace?  Also, your method to handle the download?

Comment: Download error is : Failed -Network error

Comment: try {
   byte barr[] = file.getBytes();
   BufferedOutputStream bout = new BufferedOutputStream(
     new FileOutputStream(path + "/" + filename));
   // multipartFile.transferTo(new File(saveDirectory + fileName));
   // fileNames.add(fileName);
   bout.write(barr);
   bout.flush();
   bout.close();

  } catch (Exception e) {